# Is this factorial function from a C tutorial wrong?

Tags: c

I have a little programming experience in Python, and for the sake of curiosity I started to learn C, at least the very basics. In a tutorial, I found an example function for calculating a factorial, which is this:

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i < x; i++)
    {
        x *= i;  
    }
    return x;
}
```

I also added these lines in order to see the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int val;
    val = factorial(5);
    printf("%d\n",val);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled the code with `gcc factor.c -o factor.out`, run and... ooops, the result is `-1899959296`, clearly there's something wrong.

After a couple of tries, using `printf()` to print both `i` and `x`, I figured out what went wrong (I think): since the condition of the `for` loop checks if the counter is less than `x`, and at each step `x` gets bigger and bigger, `i` is always less than `x`, so the loop keeps going on, presumably stopping when the value of `x` is too big (which should be related to `int`, I'm not very familiar yet with the various data types).

So, to "solve" the problem, I rewrote the function like this:

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int counter = x;
    int number = x;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i < counter; i++)
    {
        number *= i;
    }
    return number;
}
```

I compiled the program, run, and the value printed is 120, which is correct.

I searched a little bit for examples of factorial functions in C, and found many solutions much better than mine, taking into account negative numbers and formats like `long` and whatnot, but all of them, in a way or another, seem to rely on two "main" variables, much like my solution.

So, the final question: is the example proposed wrong, or am I missing something? This really bothers me, because if such a simple example is blatantly wrong, I should question the credibility of the rest.

Comment: Get a C book and read about `INT_MAX` etc.

Comment: `If such a simple example is blatantly wrong, I should question the credibility of the rest.` - Yes, absolutely. Not because they got a simple thing wrong, but because they didn't test their stuff before publishing it.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is complete and I see no reason why it should be taken as off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, indeed. The original factorial function is wrong for exactly the reason you've identified. You can't use `x` as both the accumulator and loop limit.

In your version, one improvement I'd suggest is to get rid of `counter`. Since you're no longer modifying `x`,  you don't need to save off a copy of it.

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int number = x;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i < x; i++)
    {
        number *= i;
    }
    return number;
}
```

You could do this without additional variables if you reverse the loop.

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = x - 1; i > 1; i--)
    {
        x *= i;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I wouldn't write it this way, though. Modifying an input parameter is poor style.

Answer (score 2):

I think by putting loop condition `i<=x` and using another variable to store factorial will correct it.

**Here is the example:**

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int i;
    int fact = 1; //store factorial
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

Or you can use recursive function

```
int factorial(int x) {
    if (x == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, these are both possible valid solutions. However, the point is still valid: the example given was wrong!

Comment: What do you mean by example given ? in your question ?

Comment: Yes, the first function provided by the tutorial

Comment: Ok! I edited my first solution like your example. You can see that.